# Promise Error in node-express, result not getting stored in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

Simply, I want to store results in this array and want this result outside `this.data` function I want to pass these results as `this.data` and when I'm importing this function i use `this.data`

```
database = admin.database();

class PrivateSingleton {
  constructor() {
    let a = [];
    const keyref = database.ref("data");
    const finalfinaldata = keyref.get().then((data) => {
      const finalData = data.val();
      // console.log(finalData)
      return finalData;
    });

    this.data = finalfinaldata.then(function (result) {
      // console.log(result);
      a.push(result);
    });
    console.log(a);

    this.iv = "IVVV";
    this.key = "aaa";
  }
}

class Singleton {
  constructor() {
    throw new Error("Use Singleton.getInstance()");
  }

  static getInstance() {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      Singleton.instance = new PrivateSingleton();
    }
    return Singleton.instance;
  }
}

module.exports = Singleton;
```

OUTPUT

```
  : [] // Here I want my result in this array.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Also you're exporting `Singleton` rather than `PrivateSingleton`.

Comment: [@Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377002/andy) Edited! Check now!

Comment: Post by @jonrsharpe should get you a long way. Also, keep in mind that your constructors can't be async, since constructors need to return the object it constructs (and not a Promise), so you need to call your async initialization logic via another method. Lastly, you could consider making Singleton's constructor private, that way you can catch violations at compile time rather than run time.